# How to install dependencies via Composer for Symfony project in Dockerfile?

Tags: php, symfony, docker, composer-php

I've met a problem related to making Docker container image, that contains Symfony base application. I can install php extensions without any problem (mcrypt, pdo_mysql, etc), but I can't install dependencies via Composer.

So... I've got, that I have problems related to caching and forming file `autoload.php`. I can't understand why, but it tries connect database. I assume it, because I get following message:

```
    Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception


      [RuntimeException]
      An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:

        [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
        An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory


        [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
        SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory


        [PDOException]
        SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I've tried to install by command `composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader` and it is finished successful. But I can't install assets without file autoload.php.

Is it possible install to Docker container image with Symfony based project dependencies and assets? Thank you!

Comment: Symfony containers exist on docker hub, so presumably it is possible. Ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/jakubsacha/symfony-docker/

Answer (score 0):

One of your bundles in the `AppKernel` requires a database connection during the compilation of the kernel (warming up the cache). You will need to debug which of the bundles does this by disabling them one at the time.

Probably if you disable all of them (except for the Symfony ones) building the container works just fine.

So the problem basically lies in these two lines of the `post-install-cmd`, for my project on Platform.sh removing these lines allowed me to build the container:

```
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
```

Comment: Ok, it works fine. But your suggest means, that I can't install assets during building an container image. Am I correct understand?

Comment: Yes you can, but some of the assets that are installed or cache entries that are generated require a connection to the database. You can trigger these two commands post-build.